# First name last name validation asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

how do validate  first name and last name in visual basic 2015 webfrom, i am new the fields for both first name and last name is required and it has to be English letters, apostrophe and hyphen only, also if add more fields e.g. dob address, do i validate them with a button, if so how. Thanks, new and learning

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to msdn on how to add validation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx

For the regex to validate first and last name, use `[a-zA-Z/'/-]+`